# How to get selected fields value size in mongodb using aggregate

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

{
"_id" : 1,
"companyID" : 1,
"counter" : 3222,
"shipper" : [
{
"_id" : 0,
"counter" : 0,
"shipperName" : "WEST LIBERTY FOODS",
"shipperAddress" : "207 W 2ND STREET",
"shipperLocation" : "WEST LIBERTY, IA ",
"shipperPostal" : "52776",
"shipperContact" : "Jolene- SHIPPING",
"shipperEmail" : "",
"shipperTelephone" : "3196276320",
"shipperExt" : "",
"shipperTollFree" : "",
"shipperFax" : "",
"shipperShippingHours" : "24 HOURS",
"shipperAppointments" : "Yes",
"shipperIntersaction" : "",
"shipperStatus" : "Active",
"shippingNotes" : "",
"internalNotes" : "",
"insertedTime" : 1589646580,
"insertedUserId" : "NBP Technology LLP",
"deleteStatus" : 0
}
]
}

Comment: Please do read [How to ask good questions on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to get visibility and help from the community. welcome and good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're asking is how to get the size of the `shipper` array.  To get the size of the `shipper` array, you can create an aggregation pipeline like the following:

```
[{$addFields: {
  numberOfShippers: {$size: "$shipper"}
}}]
```